# How can I switch to the graphic editor in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm unable to switch to the graphic editor in Android Studio. I have only then XML editor (no preview or palette pane). How can I find this editor?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Activities aren't attached to graphic editors.
If you're talking about the *design view* you have to click the **"Design" tab** that is to the left of the Text tab, at the bottom of the editor window.
Take a look to the attached screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

This is a closer look to that tab
[image: Tab]

Anyway if you are in the "text" view you can view a *preview* of the layout, by clicking the **"preview" panel** that it's placed at the top right of the screen, take a look to the next screenshot.
[image: preview tab]

Finally this is a general view with those panels expanded, hope it helps:
[image: All options expanded]

Comment: If you solved the problem, please, mark the question as answered :)

Comment: As solange points out in the following post, you might not be able to see these two bottom tabs, "Design" and "Text", if you're using the darker Dracula theme. Switch back to the Default theme and see if they are there. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18736057/293280)

Comment: It also helps to click on the *.xml file under the "res" folder in the file overview panel