# Android Studio Update from 0.6.0 to 0.6.1 failed

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio, updates

Just wondering what could cause something like this and if there is a quick fix without reinstalling all together, I don't mind missing out on this update, but will it 'fix' itself by the time 0.6.2 rolls out?

[image: Update failure dialog]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't update Android Studio - Access Denied and java.io.FileNotFoundException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646604/cant-update-android-studio-access-denied-and-java-io-filenotfoundexception)

Comment: Thanks Scott I have found a solution different to the others there and will post my answer in that thread